# how to compare ImageVerifier text with the textbox value using comparevalidator in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, password-recovery, comparevalidator

I am using PasswordRecoverycontrol in asp.net and have placed Imageverifier in the question template of this control which has captcha image. I want to compare the imageverifier text and the text user enters in the textbox below the image using comparevalidator. I cannot do it in code behind because a lot of methods run once the page loads and I want to avoid that if the text doesn't match.

Comment: Not possible. The compare validator is using javascript code to eval a condition. How do you get the text from the image using javascript? You can't, unless you use some OCR javascript library and which might give you the correct text (depends on how good is your captcha, but you're already hijacking you captcha)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2019/passwordrecovery-with-captcha

cheers,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Well Thank you guys for your input . I was able to solve this problem. As PasswordRecovery_VerifyingAnswer event i compared the value in textbox and the image text in ImageVerifier and threw Exception and added e.cancel=true which prevented the code to run any further and displayed the error message in failuretext label.